# C# OpenTK MouseMove Dynamic Declaration

Tags: c#, opentk

I am using the latest OpenTK version in C# and I have a class called LevelRenderer() that inherits the GLControl form.

I have dynamically defined the events as such:

```
        Load += new EventHandler(Control_Load);
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Control_Paint);
        MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseMove);
        MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseWheel);
        MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseUp);
        MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseDown);
```

However, the MouseDown line has an error thrown:

> Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MouseButtons' and 'MouseEventHandler'

The class itself is defined as such:

```
    private void Control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I'm not completely sure how to approach this error, and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error you show states that you try to use the operator "+=" on the wrong types.

If this error is reported on the "MouseDown" line, that means that the term `MouseDown` is not an event, but an instance of type `MouseButtons`.
As there is no such class in OpenTK, you might want to check if you have accidentally created a field or property called `MouseDown` that is of that type.

Comment: please dont say 'throw' for compiler errors, it encourages lack of clarity by the questioners. Runtime errors are 'thrown', compile time errors are 'reported'

Comment: @pm100 You're absolutely right, I missed that. Will change